# Regd:Immutable Objects for MultiThreaded Application

Tags: java

If we create a Immutable class, as below for correctness of the state of Student object,then is there any way to create a new Object as we do for String without calling getInstance method as in this case?

```
 public class Student {

    private final StringBuffer name;
    private final int roll;
    private static Student student;

    private Student(StringBuffer name , int roll)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public static Student getInstance(StringBuffer name,int roll)
    {
        student = new Student(name, roll);
        return student;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with calling `getInstance` or just exposing the constructor?

Comment: @AshishAggarwal, the returned `Student` is still immutable.  Also, it's not a singleton as a new object is created for every invocation of `getInstance`.  However, there is a race condition if `getInstance` is called concurrently, as one thread could get the instance created by another thread (with potentially different `name` and `roll`).

Comment: Agreed.Thanks.So everytime for this Student object call the constructor to update the reference variable with new Object.

Comment: @Ullas, why do you need a static instance of `Student`?

Comment: I thought it is one of the steps for Immutability

Comment: @Simon..If I use a private Lock and obtain a lock using synchronized block using this lock inside the constructor will it be immutable and thread safe?

Comment: An immutable object is an instance of a class that has no state that can be modified.  There are restrictions on the number of instances of an immutable object.  In your example, you can simplify your class by just making the constructor public and removing the `getInstance` method.  However, you may be getting confused between an immutable object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), and a singleton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Yes still there is a way to create a new instance without calling getInstance method of your class. That way is to call clone on an instance of Student class. So override clone method and stop that if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable object means the object whose state cannot be changed after its construction.  So, you can change your code to something like below, and it is still immutable (as there is no way to change the state of the object once it is constructed - no setters) but at the same time can be constructed freely without any restrictions:

Also, in your code state was not accessible as you did not have any getter methods, it must be added as shown below.

```
public class Student {

    private int roll;
    private String name;

    private Student(String name , int roll)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

}
```

You need to implement equals() and hashCode() method (or conveniently generate using `Eclipse -> Source -> Generated hashCode() and equals()...`

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance directly with "normal" code, but you can bypass the "private" keyword using reflection:

```
Constructor<Student> c = Student.class.getDeclaredConstructor(StringBuffer.class, int.class);
c.setAccessible(true); // there goes private!
Student s = c.newInstance(new StringBuffer("Bob"), 6);
```